# Disable button until the "fetch" is done

Tags: javascript, button, fetch

I'm trying to disable `import_button` when I click it and enable it when the `fetch` is done.
I tried to do it like this (code below) but unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Sub question: Can I skip this two lines of code `let import_button = document.getElementById('import_button'); import_button.disabled = true;` and do something like this? `this.disabled = true;`

```
<button id="import_button" onclick="fetchProducts(event);">Import</button>
```

```
function fetchProducts(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let import_button = document.getElementById('import_button');
    import_button.disabled = true;
    
    fetch('/api/v1/products', {
        method: 'GET'
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(products => 
        import_result.innerHTML = `Updated: ${products.updated}`
      )
      .then(import_button.disabled = false)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That final `then` still needs to be a function

```
.then(() => import_button.disabled = false)
```

or just include it in previous `then`

```
.then(products => {
    import_result.innerHTML = `Updated: ${products.updated}`;
    import_button.disabled = false
  })
```

Sub question: sort of. It's the event target

```js
function fetchProducts(e){
  let import_button = e.target;
   console.log(import_button)
   import_button.disabled = true;  
}
```

```html
<button id="import_button" onclick="fetchProducts(event);">Import</button>
```

So make it `let import_button = e.target`

Answer (score 1):

You should consider changing the disabled state inside `finally` instead of `then` so that you can handle the `catch` error as well.

You can store button reference using `this`:

```
function fetchProducts(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let import_button = this;
    
    import_button.disabled = true;
    
    fetch('/api/v1/products', {
        method: 'GET'
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(products => 
        import_result.innerHTML = `Updated: ${products.updated}`
      )
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
      .finally(() => (import_result.disabled = false))
}
```